# screenrecord not working in emulator

Tags: android-emulator, screen-recording

Since 4.4 KitKat, Android has a shell utility screenrecord to record the Android device screen.

If I connect a physical device with the adb utility over USB, I can do the following:

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/sample.mp4
adb pull /sdcard/sample.mp4
```

But if I do the above for an Android emulator, I will get an empty sample.mp4 file.

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/sample.mp4
adb shell ls -l /sdcard/sample.mp4
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r        0 2016-06-18 05:37 sample.mp4
```

If I execute screenrecord directly in a root console in emulator, I see the following:

```
root@flo:/system/bin # ./screenrecord /sdcard/sample.mp4                       
[1] + Stopped (signal)     ./screenrecord /sdcard/sample.mp4 
root@flo:/system/bin # 
[1] + Illegal instruction  ./screenrecord /sdcard/sample.mp4
```

Why does screenrecord not work for emulator?

Comment: AOSP Issue 61682: Screenrecord doesn't work with emulator, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61682 , You can vote for it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screenrecord uses MediaCodec API. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html

To be precise, Screenrecord directly calls the native interface of MediaCodec.

To the best of my knowledge, no emulator supports MediaCodec yet. They all support higher level interface MediaPlayer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html.

Answer (score 0):

Screenrecord is working with `Android Emulator v27.0.2`.

I've tested it with `Oreo x86 with Google Play` image, but it should work with any KitKat+ image.